# Break dentro de un loop que continue evaluando los valores

Tags: python

Estoy analizando todos los elementos de una lista, el problema que tengo es que el break me rompe todo el loop y lo que quiero es que deje de analizar el x que estoy evaluando en mylist solamente

```
import itertools

mylist = [54,345,3456,345,234,34,654,345,65]

for x,y in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
    if x < y:
        print(x,y)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Es que no sabia como explicarlo, lo que quiero es que si cumple la condicion siga analizando el x vs los y pero que si no corte ahi el analisis del x, me explico?

Comment: en mi ejemplo, para el primer valor que seria 54 deberia imprimir hasta el 234 y luego analizar el siguiente x que seria 345 y hacer el mismo analisis

Comment: has probado a usar continue en lugar de break?

Answer (score 2):

`itertools.combinations` retorna un iterador que va generando a petición una a una las tuplas con las combinaciones posibles, no hay una forma directa, simple y eficiente de hacer lo que quieres usándolo. Aunque puedes simplemente ignorar las combinaciones hasta que otra "x" sea retornada, por ejemplo:

```
import itertools

mylist = [54,345,3456,345,234,34,654,345,65]

last = None 
for x, y in itertools.combinations(mylist, 2):
    if last != x:
        if x < y:
            print(x, y)
        else:
            last = x
```

Dado que buscas las combinaciones de dos elementos, creo que lo más simple es que generes tu mismo las combinaciones usando dos `for` anidados y un condicional con `break` que rompa el `for` anidado:

```
mylist = [54, 345, 3456, 345, 234, 34, 654, 345, 65]

for i, x in enumerate(mylist):
    for y in mylist[i+1: ]:
        if x >= y:
            break
        print(x, y)
```

> ```
> 54 345
> 54 3456
> 54 345
> 54 234
> 345 3456
> 34 654
> 34 345
> 34 65
> ```